# How to properly call internal js.file after building in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with initializing internal file.

Specifically https://www.detectadblock.com/

I can't initialize this ads.js file on my project.

```
var e=document.createElement('div');
e.id='punVTqCWOHsB';
e.style.display='none';
document.body.appendChild(e);
```

My web browser always failed with loaded script. Any suggestions how can I proceed?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code? That is only step two from the linked page, and is written in JS, not in GWT/Java.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dK7JayfSRb

Comment: In other words can I use this script in gwt project?

Comment: Looks like the GWT tag was removed - maybe put it back, and add the GWT code you have so far to the question? Sharing the error you are getting would be good too. Yes, the JS described on that page can all be easily written in GWT/Java as well.

Comment: Please can you show me some precise documention for this? Or some little example I can’t found something relevant.

Comment: There is no documentation on how to use that detect-adblock method with GWT, but the JS can be written in GWT/Java using existing Document, Element classes. You say "My web browser always failed with loaded script" - can you put the code that failed and the error message you got in your question?

Comment: So my problem is I try to call my ads.js file in HTML but I always make something on the bad way. I think it is necessary to call my ads.js file on AdBlock.java file but it is just my doubt. So you can check my HTML file my ads.js file and also AdBlock.java file. And of course, on developer tools in a browser, I have always this warning statement" Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8888/AdBlock/src/com/example/myproject/public/ads.js”." https://github.com/marosmamrak/AdBlock-1.git  --> there you can find files where I try to use JSNI with also example from tutorial

Answer (score 0):

> Loading failed for the  with source “127.0.0.1:8888/AdBlock/src/com/example/myproject/public/ads‌​.js”." github.com/marosmamrak/AdBlock-1.git

You are giving the full path to the *source files* (in `src/.../public`), but that file will be copied with the rest of the GWT compiled sources, so it should be inside the `adblock` directory to match your .nocache.js file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="adblock/adblock.nocache.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="adblock/ads.js"></script>
```

---

Also please note that this does nothing at all, since the browser can't execute Java files directly:

```
<script src="/AdBlock/src/com/example/myproject/client/Flipper.java"></script>
```